# How to filter list of dictionaries with matching values for a given key

Tags: python, list, dictionary, filter

With an interface like `a = copyf(dictlist, key, valuelist)`.

```
>>> dictlist = [{'first': 'James',
                 'last': 'Joule'},
                {'first': 'James',
                 'last': 'Watt'},
                {'first': 'Christian',
                 'last': 'Doppler'}]
>>> valuelist = ['James', 'John']
>>> x = copyf(dictlist, 'first', valuelist)
>>> print(x)
[{'first': 'James',
  'last': 'Joule'},
 {'first': 'James',
  'last': 'Watt'}]
```

The `dictlist` is effectively a `csv.DictReader` instance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Update:** taking into account the reedited question of the OP:

```
def copyf(dictlist, key, valuelist):
      return [dictio for dictio in dictlist if dictio[key] in valuelist]
```

Answer (score 6):

Probably not the best solution, but here we go:

```
>>> def copyf(data, key, allowed):
...     return filter(lambda x: key in x and x[key] in allowed, data)
... 
>>> dictlist = [{'first': 'James', 'last': 'Joule'}, {'first': 'James','last': 'Watt'},{'first': 'Christian','last': 'Doppler'}]
>>> copyf(dictlist, 'first', ('Christian',))
[{'last': 'Doppler', 'first': 'Christian'}]
>>> copyf(dictlist, 'last', ('Christian',))
[]
>>> copyf(dictlist, 'first', ('James',))
[{'last': 'Joule', 'first': 'James'}, {'last': 'Watt', 'first': 'James'}]
>>>
```

Comment: @plaes, you can turn the list comprehension into a generator expression by dropping the square brackets.  This is in keeping with what your usage of iteritems() is trying to accomplish by avoiding the creation of an intermediate list.

Comment: @kevpie: Thanks, will fix \o/

Comment: @plaes, probably the OP was asking to filter by values not by keys. Note the function parameters given (dictionary, key, valuelist).

Comment: @joaquin: Now that I look it again, it might be like that. :S

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity, I have provided a usage example.

Answer (score 2):

Something like

```
new_dict = dict((k, v) for k,v in old_dict.items() if v in allowed_values)
```

?

Comment: you are removing all coincident values indepently of the key. The OP question said  "matching values (**for a given key**) from a list" and actually gave 'key' as a function parameter. Maybe he changed his mind...or I misunderstood?

Comment: in a dict, there can only be 0 or 1 value per given key. this sort of distracted me from the phrase you boldfaced. sorry! :)

Comment: Well, you got the "accepted answer". Hope it is not due homework :-))

Comment: Accepted answers change sometimes. Statistically it pays to give a superior answer even if the question already has a low-scored accepted answer (like mine here). Note that a fuller answer with the same approach now scores twice as high.

Comment: Sorry guys, I was super tired when I posted the question and accepted this answer. This doesn't take "for a given key" into consideration.

Comment: It's totally ok. The right answer ought to be accepted, and a wrong answer, no matter how much upvoted, ought not.

Answer (score 1):

Clean and neat, using **filter** and **lambda**

```
>>> def copyf(dictlist, key, valuelist):
...     filter(lambda d: d[key] in valuelist, dictlist)
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer

> filter(lambda d: value in d[key], dictlist)