# How to copy dictionaries with matching values for a given key from list to new list?

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Copy dictionaries with matching values for a given key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5762643/copy-dictionaries-with-matching-values-for-a-given-key)

With an interface like `a = copyf(dictlist, key, valuelist)`.

```
>>> dictlist = [{'first': 'James',
                 'last': 'Joule'},
                {'first': 'James',
                 'last': 'Watt'},
                {'first': 'Christian',
                 'last': 'Doppler'}]
>>> valuelist = ['James', 'John']
>>> x = copyf(dictlist, 'first', valuelist)
>>> print(x)
[{'first': 'James',
  'last': 'Joule'},
 {'first': 'James',
  'last': 'Watt'}]
```

The `dictlist` is effectively a `csv.DictReader` instance.

Comment: shouldn't that be copyf(dictlist, 'first', accepted_values)?

Comment: And why would you want to copy them? Can't you simple use references to the original dicts?

Comment: I don't understand why you're asking this question again.

Comment: -1 for duping your own question.

Comment: @odonnell, you must only to modify the original post, not to re-post it again (and modify the original at the same time).

Comment: What do you suggest doing when your question gets downvoted and everyone ignores it based on a couple peoples' assessment of it at posting?

Comment: joaquin: it's not that I don't know how to edit the question, it's that it will be ignored by most people due to its rating, which was based on the original question. If there was a way to edit a question and reset the vote count, this problem wouldn't exist, but people would probably abuse it.

Comment: delnan: how would you do this using only simple references?

Comment: What makes you think people were ignoring it? You had only edited it an hour ago. You should at least have given it some more time.

Comment: You're right, sorry. But one has to admit downvotes are sometimes a burden on an edited question, and that sometimes the answers to an edited question are so unrelated that the question should really just be closed to avoid confusion, but the posted doesn't have that authority. Should I have waited until the original was officially closed?

Comment: @odonnel: *Everything* in Python is a reference (not references as in pass-by-reference, more like pointers without the pointer arithmetic part). `d = {}; ds = [d]` just makes `d` refer to a dictionary object somewhere and puts a reference to the same object into a list as well. Copying would mean copying all the (references to) keys and values, which is wasteful and only warranted if you need to be independent from changes anyone else does to the dictionary in the meantime.

Answer (score 3):

```
x = [d for d in dictlist if d['first'] in valuelist]
```

Comment: Works better if `valuelist` is a set, by the way.

Comment: This is O(n^2), I would wrap valuelist in a set.

Comment: Thanks for focusing on the question.

Answer (score 0):

This alternative returns a copy of the dictionaries:

```
def copyf(dictlist, key, valuelist)
        return [copy.deepcopy(dictio) for dictio in dictlist if dictio[key] in valueList]
```