# Checking if a list exist in a list of dictionaries without loops

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

How can I check if a list exists as a value in a dictionary which is a member of a list (list of dictionaries)?

```
totalList = ([{'score': 1, 'item': ['text1', 'text2']},
              {'score': 2, 'item': ['text3', 'text4']},
              {'score': 3, 'item': ['text5', 'text6']}])
redList = ['text1', 'text2']
```

A one-liner such as this (though this one doesn't work for obvious reasons). I want to avoid loops.

```
if redList in totalList:
    print("True")
```

Context:

```
redlists = a list of lists
totalList = []
for redlist in redlists:
   if redlist not in totalList:
      totalList.append(dictionary_item))
```

Example `ditcionary_item` = `{'score': 1, 'item': ['text1', 'text2']}`

**Note:** Total list keeps growing because every time redList is not in the totalList, I add a new dictionary to the toalList based on predefined criteria.

Comment: Here is a possible duplicate question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5762643/how-to-filter-list-of-dictionaries-with-matching-values-for-a-given-key

Comment: the dictionary is always the first element of the list, or at the same index ?

Comment: **Why** do you want to avoid loops?

Comment: @PRMoureu didn't really get your question but each dictionary stays at the same index once added to the list.

Comment: @StefanPochmann this piece of code is already inside loops so want to avoid a big nested loop. I can create a function for the check but was wondering if there will be another way to do it as a one-liner like a normal list membership check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
any(d['item'] == redList for d in totalList)
```

Or with [operator.itemgetter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

```
redList in map(itemgetter('item'), totalList)
```

Edit: Or just a generator expression (similar to Leandro's, but more space-efficient and perhaps more time-efficient as well, since it stops at the first finding):

```
redList in (d['item'] for d in totalList)
```

Comment: will go with the itemgetter/map option.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this

```
if redList in [x.get('item') for x in totalList]:
    print("True")`
```

Answer (score 1):

If you often need this check, it might be worth it to  convert your lists to tuples. This way, they become [hashable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14535739/6419007) and can be saved in a `set`:

```
totalList = [{'score': 1, 'item': ['text1', 'text2']},
             {'score': 2, 'item': ['text3', 'text4']},
             {'score': 3, 'item': ['text5', 'text6']}]

items = {tuple(d['item']) for d in totalList}
print(items)
# {('text3', 'text4'), ('text1', 'text2'), ('text5', 'text6')}
redList = ['text1', 'text2']
print(tuple(redList) in items)
# True
```

You only need to iterate once in order to create the set. Every check will be fast and won't require any loop.

If you want to get the corresponding score, you could save the tuples in a dict:

```
scores = {tuple(d['item']):d['score'] for d in totalList}
print(scores)
# {('text1', 'text2'): 1, ('text3', 'text4'): 2, ('text5', 'text6'): 3}

print(scores.get(tuple(redList), 0))
# 1
print(scores.get(tuple(['a', 'b']), 0))
# 0
```

Comment: that's indeed a better solution, however, totalList keeps growing so its not a static list. Forgot to mention that in question. Just updated the question. Everytime the redlist is not in the totallist, I add a new dictionary to Totallist.

Comment: @utengr: No problem. `items` and `scores` are mutable. You can add new tuples any time you want.

Comment: you are right. I  can add a new tuple to items every time I update totalList.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter`:

```
redList = ['text1', 'text2']
totalList = ([{'score': 1, 'item': ['text1', 'text2']},
          {'score': 2, 'item': ['text3', 'text4']},
          {'score': 3, 'item': ['text5', 'text6']}])
if list(filter(lambda x:x["item"] == redList, totalList)):
    print('redList in totalList')
```